# Why doesn't MST3K release its episodes in chronological order?

Tags: continuity, mst3k

When episodes of Mystery Science Theater 3000 (MST3K) are released in packages on DVD, they seem to release them in a random order- one episode from a later season may come before one of the earlier seasons, for example. Is there a particular reason for this randomness?

Comment: It looks like it's mostly down to rights issues and a desire to match like films to each other; http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_DVD_releases

Comment: I edited the question to add the definition of MST3K in the question, as not everyone is familiar with that franchise.

Comment: @Loki The full name is visible when the user hovers the mst3k tag.

Comment: @MrLister Hovering over a tag doesn't work on a mobile...

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue confronting Best Brains (which, through most of the relevant period meant basically producer Jim Mallon) efforts to get the full library of MST3K episodes released is the rights to the films.  For the earliest episodes, the show's makers sometimes only obtained the rights to use the films for the original run; later, with more experience, the typically got the rights to use the films they were riffing on for a first run, and eventually in syndication.  However, the rights they obtained did not typically include rights to release the films on VHS or DVD.  So in order to have a DVD release of a film, Best Brains had to go back to whoever owned the copyrights for the original films (and sometimes the films had changed hands since the MST3K episodes had been made) and negotiate a contract that would allow Best Brains to release the films, with riffing, on DVD.

This meant there was a complicated interplay of factors in deciding which episodes to release.  Obviously, it had to be possible to get the rights.  And sometimes those rights were subject to secondary encumbrances; some rights holders wanted a DVD release to include the original version of a film, as well as the MST3K-riffed version.  (This kind of thing actually happened during the original run of the show as well.  The makers of *The Quest of the Delta Knights* insisted that the film be shown as a regular feature on the Sci-Fi Channel before the MST3K version premiered.)  There was also the issue that Best Brains typically wanted to release the funniest episodes possible.  The riffing in many of the earlier-season episodes is just not as good as in the later run of the show.  There were also disagreements between Best Brains and the cast members who had left to work on other projects (specifically Mike Nelson, Kevin Murphy, and Bill Corbett, who worked first of *Film Crew*, then *RiffTrax*) over which which group of riffers would get the rights to particular films.

Comment: This all seems very plausible, but can you offer any **evidence** that this is the case?